# How to change users mail attribute in drupal via API?

Tags: drupal

How would I change a users email address via an API? In the DB the column is users.mail.

I would like to call Drupal, via REST, from another application to change a user's email address.

I am using Drupal 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) and the wealth of [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/109782) associated with it.